# Mean app login not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have followed many tutorials on how to get mongodb and MEAN to work on heroku, and none of them have worked for me, I keep getting the 503 application error.

First I create the app, I do `heroku addons:docs mongolab` in the commandline, and after that I check my config and change my code so the mongoose connection is changed to the config string like this: 
`mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || mongodb://example:example@ds053312.mongolab.com:53312/todolist');`
the second part is just an example, the one I use is the one with my information.
So after this I push my app to heroku, but when I try to run it, it still gives me the application error, and in f12 it says it's

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
>   (Service Unavailable)
>    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico

What am I doing wrong? I have tried everything and none of the tutorials are working for me

EDIT: I have managed to get rid of the error by doing the following:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial version"

$ heroku apps:create
```

however, now that my app loads, it appears that the login and sign up features of my app doesn't work, I fill out the sign in/log in form and submit but the page just stays where it is without changing. Is there something else I was supposed to do to get these features to work?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? They are under the "More" dropdown in the top right of your app dashboard.

Comment: I have edited my post with the logs

Comment: post more logs by typing `heroku logs -n 25` in your command line, the error is before the logs you posted.  Looks like perhaps something is being required that's not in your dependencies, but hard to say what it is from there.

Comment: I have updated with the new log, does this mean this is because of something else and not my incorrect setup of mongodb on heroku?

Comment: `Cannot find module './drivers'` I guess you are doing `require("./drivers")`. Can you update with your directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

I came here because my Heroku - deploy Login wasn't working, but Localhost was.  Turns out I forgot to change the Login POST route.